AEM CaaS: ReplicationAction not finding generated sitemap hence 404
We have sitemap generator working perfectly for top level locale files (i.e us/en/sitemap.xml). However when it comes to lower level pages sitemaps, ReplicationAction is failing to find those files due to path mismatch. For example sitemap for /us/en/about-us/newsroom page is generated under /var/sitemaps/ and as
/content/xxx/us/en/about-us-newsroom-sitemap.xml.
However ReplicationAction is failing to find resource under
/content/xxx/us/en.sitemap.about-us-newsroom-sitemap.xml
Which means ReplicationAction is finding file at wrong place or generated name is incorrect. I dug into ReplicationAction documentation but could not find where I can force it to look into right folder and files. In logs ReplicationAction is failing with following warning
WARN [sling-default-1] com.adobe.cq.cloudconfig.core.impl.ConfigurationReplicationEventHandler Resource [/content/xxx/us/en.sitemap.about-us-newsroom-sitemap.xml] not found for ReplicationAction and hence throws 404 when it is accessed on publish instance
Any help is appreciated
